# Accidental Presses With Smart Keyboard Folio

Tags: ipad, magic-keyboard-ipad, smart-keyboard

I plan to buy the iPad Air with the Smart Keyboard Folio and Apple Pencil soon. I noticed that if you're using the iPad flat on a surface, the keyboard is essentially face-down into that surface. Can anyone who own a Smart Keyboard Folio tell me if using the iPad like this and pressing the screen causes the keys on the keyboard to accidentally press against the surface? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys are disabled when you flip it over - so accidental presses is not a problem there.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that!!! Thanks. Hard to tell when you don't have it in front of you